# Cannot find device android studio | ADB Shows Device But Studio Can't

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, device

**ADB Devices successfully recognizing phone**

[image]

**Device not recognized by Android Studio**

[image]

**SDK tools installed**

[image]

- Launched Android Studio in the morning
- Went away for an hour approx.
- Came back and carried on coding
- Updated IDE to 3.6/3.6.1 (can't remember)
- Device no longer shows up for deployment.

---

- USB Debugging enabled.
- Install via USB enabled.
- Platform tools installed.
- Device tried in FTP & PTP.
- Clean uninstalled Android Studio via several terminal rm dir commands.
- Restarted machine & phone
- Tried installing Android Studio 3.4 & 3.5 releases.

Answer (score 0):

I have a quick fix for this problem. Just copy everything from `~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/platform-tools` to `~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools`.

I think AS is buggy and the last update moved everything from the `...platform-tools` folder to `.../platform-tools/platform-tools`.